# How to delete world (unlink) fwithout get the Name (2.8)

Tags: python, world

How to delete world without get the name of world in blender 2.8.
For add world i use `new_world = bpy.data.worlds.new(my_var_string)
but name change by string. I think : can delete "Active world" without name?
i try:`bpy.data.worlds.remove()`but that line need a world  .. i think  if is possible delete world in use?

Comment: `bpy.data.worlds.remove(new_world)`

Comment: sorry @batFINGER your example is right but not work for me because i create a class with button panel for delete world background

Comment: maybe `if context.world: bpy.data.worlds.remove(context.world)` to totally remove that world, or do you want to just unlink from scene?

Comment: @batFINGER your example give me error: context object has no attribute 'world'

Comment: * `context.scene.world`  (`context.world` is only available in the PROPERTIES space)

Comment: @batFINGER This is exactly what I was looking for. if you want to put it in the answer is the correct answer to my problem